# Bind property to a radio group value

Tags: binding, model, dojo

Lets say I have a group of radio buttons:

```
<span data-dojo-type="Scripts/Framework/UI/Form/RadioButton" data-dojo-props="value:1,name:'Foo'"></span>
<span data-dojo-type="Scripts/Framework/UI/Form/RadioButton" data-dojo-props="value:2,name:'Foo'"></span>
<span data-dojo-type="Scripts/Framework/UI/Form/RadioButton" data-dojo-props="value:3,name:'Foo'"></span>
```

How do I bind this to a model property `Foo` so that its value is set to the value of the selected radio button? I tried binding it to the `checked` property and then applying transform, but ran into issues with overwriting model value when button is being unchecked.

```
<span data-dojo-type="Scripts/Framework/UI/Form/RadioButton"
data-dojo-props="value:3,checked:at('rel:', 'Foo').transform({format:function(x) { return x == this.value; }, parse:function(x) { return x ? this.value : /* ok, now what??? */ }})"
></span>
```

It feels like this should be way simpler than this to begin with...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`dojox/form/CheckMultiSelect`](https://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dojox/form/CheckedMultiSelect) widget provides the capabilities to `get` and `set` the selected radio button of a group easily.

If you take the example code in the [tutorial](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/form/CheckedMultiSelect.html) for radio buttons and then experiment with setting and getting the `value` from the group, you will soon see that you can then start binding the value of a model state.

I had to read through the API docs for the widget to expand on the tutorial. To get and set the value of the selected radio in a group I used the [standard `get("attr")/set("attr", value)`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/_WidgetBase.html) with the `CheckMultiSelect` widget...

```
// NOTE: make sure you have imported the dijit/registry module
// If my multi select widget has the id "multi".

// get selected value
var selectedValue = registry.byId("multi").get("value");

// set selected value
registry.byId("multi").set("value", newValue);

// getting a handle on all radio buttons
var options = registry.byId("multi").get("options");
```

The `CheckedMultiSelect` widget also extends [`_FormSelectWidget`](https://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dijit/form/_FormSelectWidget) so you can do everything with stores as you'd expect from a select based widget, which may help you bind your model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ["watch"](http://dojotoolkit.org/features/1.6/widget-watch) to watch the value of a widget for changes. First argument is the value to watch and the second is a function that is called when that value changes.

```
radioButton.watch("checked", updateFoo);
```

Here is a fiddle showing it on the native dijit radio button.

http://jsfiddle.net/a2SEP/2/

Comment: That doesn't work for my example though. You're able to set your text box value because your second value is simply the inverse of the first one. Add a third radio button with a distinct value and you run into the same issue I did. This gets progressively more craptacular as you add buttons http://jsfiddle.net/a2SEP/3/

Comment: The problem with radio buttons is that they change the other radio buttons, calling the "watch" function again. Here is a fiddle which loops through the radio buttons when one of them changes. http://jsfiddle.net/a2SEP/5/ @llia G

Comment: All you did is carry out the handler into a separate function, which makes it only very marginally better, and still subverts all declarative binding. I am thinking there needs to be a RadioGroup widget to group manage this internally... I thought surely someone thought about this before, but it doesn't look like it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `query('selector').on('event', callback)` like so

```
query('.claro [type="radio"]').on('change', function(event) {
    textBox.set('value', event.target.id);
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/542uw/ for full example.

**NB:** basicaly you user `name` attribute to group radio buttons.